# Is this wild parsnip?

Tags: identification

I found these with yellow flowers in the field past my backyard nearby a tiny stream.  After attempting to identify it using [Virginia Tech weed id tool](https://weedid.cals.vt.edu/select/type?ptype=1&Leafstructure=3&&&Leafshape=4&&&Growthhabit=1&&&Dominantflowercolor=2&&&Leafmargin=3&&&Flowerdiameter=1), it looks like its wild parsnip, and gotta be careful with it? (At least not let kids go near it?) I'm based in Northern Virginia.  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the plant is a wildflower native to parts of Virgina called Golden Alexanders (yes, "Alexanders" is correct). Its botanical name is Zizia aurea. How do I know it's not wild parsnip? First, the height is too short. Golden Alexanders blooms anywhere from 1-2 feet tall while parsnip blooms at 3-5 feet tall. Secondly, the leaves aren't correct for parsnip but are correct for Zizia. Third, parsnip doesn't bloom this early (in Wisconsin, it's a June bloomer; I would expect it to bloom in May in Virginia, unless you're in the mountains). [Here](http://therippleeffectmn.blogspot.com/2015/06/wild-parsnip-and-its-look-alike-golden.html)'s an article from Minnesota that may help with the ID. [Here's](https://www.minnesotawildflowers.info/flower/golden-alexanders) a link from that article with photos of Zizia, including one with Golden Alexanders and Parsnip together.